# Парсинг номеров с Avito

Tags: php, парсер

Необходимо написать парсер Авито

Столкнулся с проблемой - номера на сайте представляют собой картинку

И эту картинку фиг знает как можно достать...

Comment: Какие номера?

Comment: @vasilchenkosd, я бы рекомендовал вам отказаться от затеи с вытягиванием личных телефонов.

Comment: @vasilchenkosd а с чего вы взяли, что обладатели номеров горят желанием эти самые номера вам давать? Это вообще-то личная информация, и совать в нее нос по меньшей мере некрасииво. Мало ли что вы там собрались с ними делать, может спам рассылать?

Comment: Интересуюсь не со злыми целями
Это необходимо для удобства работы и отслеживания новых объявлений

Comment: @vasilchenkosd со злыми или не со злыми, однако же вы собираетесь юзать чужие телефонные номера. Это дурная практика. Представьте, что к вам в квартиру в ваше отсутствие и без вашего ведома заявляется добрая соседская бабушка и наводит порядок по своему усмотрению, а когда вы ее за этим застаете, то она вам с невинным выражением лица заявляет: "ну я же не со злыми намерениями!". Сомневаюсь, что вам понравится подобная самодеятельность, даже если вы поверите в ее искренность

Comment: @DreamChild это совсем корректное сравнение. Номера на avito находятся в отрытом доступе и каждый желающий может их получить. Если проводить аналогию с бабушкой, то вы сами оставили ваши ключи в замке и кто то этим воспользовался.

Comment: @nekaneka ну вообще как было замечено - номера там в виде картинок. Если уж продолжать аналогии, то речь идет о ключе, спрятанном под ковриком и найденном этой хитрой бабушкой.

Comment: @DreamChild Если продолжать еще дальше, то на коврике написано - "Переверните коврик, что бы найти ключ". Думаю подобные рассуждения к теме вообще слабо относятся и смысла не имеют.

Comment: Как пользователь Авито, получающий фишинговые смски "готов купить" или "интересует обмен?" + ссылка, заряжаю лазер лучами космической диареи для нанимателей автора вопроса.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Парсите мобильную версию. Там номера в открытом виде :)
http://m.avito.ru/

Answer (score 0):

FireBug вам в помощь. Отслеживайте что и как работает. Скорее всего через AJAX  по клику на "показать номер" отправляется запрос для формирования картинки. Для распознавания потребуется написать код с использованием phpGD или php ImageMagick .